# how to connect php to oracle 11g and oracle8

Tags: php, oracle11g, oracle8

I am on linux redhat 6 enterprise. I have php set up to connect to oracle 11g, I would like to connect it to oracle 8, how can i do this?

I have tried using the current drivers installed but it does not work.

```
PHP Warning:  oci_connect(): ORA-03134: Connections to this server version are no longer supported. in /var/SP/oiadm/docroot/common/php/DatabaseConnection.php on line 112
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is because your client version (which used to compile oci8 you are using) is not compatible with Oracle 8 server.

This is the matrix (image format) for the Oracle client / server interoperabillity: [image: Matrix]

And the meaning:

[image: Legend]

Extracted from [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_client_versions_higher_lower_database_release.htm) <- where is 12 version? I'm trying to get a newer one.

Comment: is it possible to have 2 version of oracle clients installed on linux at same time?

Comment: I don't think so, or better said, even with two installed... TNS_ADMIN environment var is going to be set only to one place to use tnsnames.ora file